# What is the use of OUTPUT clause in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What is the purpose of the `OUTPUT` clause? I have gone through the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) for the `OUTPUT` clause, which includes the following example:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.table1
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO @MyTableVar
WHERE id = 4 OR id = 2;
```

From the above query, it seems that deleted records are saved in some magic table called `deleted`, and the query will load those records into table called MyTableVar from the magic `deleted` table. .

I still do not understand the purpose of the `OUTPUT` clause usage.

As another SQL example:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
DECLARE @MyTableVar table( NewScrapReasonID smallint,
                           Name varchar(50),
                           ModifiedDate datetime);
INSERT Production.ScrapReason
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ScrapReasonID, INSERTED.Name, INSERTED.ModifiedDate
        INTO @MyTableVar
VALUES (N'Operator error', GETDATE());

--Display the result set of the table variable.
SELECT NewScrapReasonID, Name, ModifiedDate FROM @MyTableVar;
--Display the result set of the table.
SELECT ScrapReasonID, Name, ModifiedDate 
FROM Production.ScrapReason;
GO
```

What is this actually doing? Can anyone explain what this clause is doing with an easy example?

### UPDATE with non-functioning example:

```
create proc test
as
CREATE TABLE dbo.table1
(
    id INT,
    employee VARCHAR(32)
)
go

INSERT INTO dbo.table1 VALUES 
      (1, 'Fred')
     ,(2, 'Tom')
     ,(3, 'Sally')
     ,(4, 'Alice')
delete from table1
select * from deleted
```

This gives me an error when I run it, because it can't see the `deleted` table.

Comment: Regarding your edit, see the comment below my answer for why this does not run. Please ask further question if this does not clear it up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The general purpose of this clause is to capture the changes made to your data without an additional query, which would introduce locking and blocking issues. Example:

```
DELETE FROM X WHERE Name = 'Foo'
```

You want to know which IDs were deleted. You can do this naively like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM X WHERE Name = 'Foo'
DELETE FROM X WHERE Name = 'Foo'
```

But these selected IDs are unreliable unless you are running in a transaction with isolation level `SERIALIZABLE` which is usually not the case. Someone else can add, delete or change "Foo"-Records between your two statements. So instead you can use the OUTPUT clause and get back exactly and reliably the deleted IDs without any performance or reliability issues.

Another frequent use is to get the value of inserted default values, especially when using identity columns. For a single insert you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE X
 (
 ID INT IDENTITY,
 Name VARCHAR(10)
 );

INSERT X (Name) VALUES ('Foo')

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

But `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` can give you only the last inserted ID. If you do multiple inserts, like

```
INSERT X (Name) VALUES ('Foo'), ('Bar')
```

or

```
INSERT X (Name) SELECT OtherName FROM Y
```

and you want to know the inserted IDs, you are out of luck. You can try to find them with another SELECT, but you need another unique column to even formulate the query and then you run into the same issues as with the `DELETE` sample above. So, the `OUTPUT` clause lets you identify neatly which Names got which IDs.

You will need these IDs for example when creating dependent records with foreign keys. Think "Order" and "OrderDetails" which are linked by an OrderID column with an `IDENTITY` clause. Again, with a single INSERT you can get away with using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or `@@IDENTITY`, but when inserting multiple orders at once, you will need `OUTPUT`.

Comment: Of course you should never use @@identity for this purpose. It can give the wrong results.

Comment: Very well explained. This helped me immensely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you perform Insert/Update/Delete operation on particular table and want to know what rows are affected OR want to log them for audit trail OR you want to use multiple values of affected rows in subsequent sql statements, you can use `OUTPUT` clause.

For Insert statement, it will have `INSERTED` table.

For Delete statement, it will have `DELETED` table. In case of Update `DELETED` table will contain rows (with old values) before update operation performed.

For Update statement, it will have `DELETED` and `INSERTED` tables. 
`DELETED` table will contain rows (with old values) before update operation performed.
`INSERTED` table will contain rows (with new values) after update operation performed.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
DECLARE @MyTableVar table( NewScrapReasonID smallint,
                           Name varchar(50),
                           ModifiedDate datetime);
INSERT Production.ScrapReason
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ScrapReasonID, INSERTED.Name, INSERTED.ModifiedDate
        INTO @MyTableVar
VALUES (N'Operator error', GETDATE());

--Display the result set of the table variable.
SELECT NewScrapReasonID, Name, ModifiedDate FROM @MyTableVar;
--Display the result set of the table.
SELECT ScrapReasonID, Name, ModifiedDate 
FROM Production.ScrapReason;
```

Now your query inserts rows in `Production.ScrapReason` as well as table variable `@MyTableVar`. Later it selects inserted rows from `Production.ScrapReason` and `@MyTableVar`. Thus you can compare both the resultset and it must have identical rows (considering `Production.ScrapReason` is empty table.)

I hope it makes sense!

**Edit:**

Inserted/Deleted tables will be available with Insert/Update/Delete statement and not after that. You may want to store those magic table values in db table or temp table.

Comment: one question how we can use sql server magic table outside of trigger but here magic table has been accessed out side of trigger using output clause. when i try to access magic table out side of trigger then i got error called Invalid object name 'deleted'.

Comment: You can use it with insert/update/delete statement in stored procedure/trigger only. Magic tables won't be available after the scope of your procedure/trigger. Better you store it in table and access it.

Comment: probably magic table can't be accessed from store proc. see my updated question & run my query.

Comment: I mean to say that you can use Inserted/deleted table with insert/update/delete statment and not after that. That's the reason you need to store it in some table.

Answer (score 0):

Without the `OUTPUT` clause, how would you know which rows were deleted? Your example seems so simple because you already know the `Id` values, but what if you did this:

```
DELETE FROM T WHERE SomeColumn LIKE 'SomePattern%'
```

And you want to find out what was deleted. That's the purpose of the `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: one question how we can use sql server magic table outside of trigger but here magic table has been accessed out side of trigger using output clause. when i try to access magic table out side of trigger then i got error called Invalid object name 'deleted'.

Comment: The inserted/deleted tables are available in two places exactly: in a trigger and in the OUTPUT clause. The two cases are unrelated (just the names of the tables happen to be the same). In both cases it is unambiguous which "magic table" is meant. You use of these tables has nothing to do with triggers. The magic table exists only for the duration of the enclosing statement.