# Optimize tsql table and/or INSERT statement that will be source for other tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a a staging table that looks like this. This will store all our data in 15-min intervals:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[15MinDataRawStaging](
    [RawId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CityId] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [int] NULL,
    [Hour] [int] NULL,
    [Minute] [int] NULL,
    [CounterValue] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CounterName] [varchar](40) NOT NULL
)
```

It currently stores 20 different Counters, which means that we insert about 400K rows every hour of every day to this table.

Right now, I'm deleting data from before 03/2016, but even with the first 8 days of March data, there's over 58M rows.

Once all the hourly data is stored in `[15MinDataRawStaging]`, we start copying data from this table to other tables, which are then used for the reports.

So, for example, we have a Kpi called *Downtime*, which is composed of counters *VeryLongCounterName1* and *VeryLongCounterName2*. Once the hourly data is stored in `[15MinDataRawStaging]`, we run a stored procedure that inserts these counters to its own table, called `[DownTime]`. It looks something like this:

```
insert into [DownTime] (CityKey, Datekey, HourKey, MinuteKey, DownTime, DowntimeType)        
select CityId, [date], [hour], [minute], CounterValue, CounterName        
From [15MinDataRawStaging] p        
where           
[date] = @Date      
and [Hour] = @Hour      
and CounterName in ('VeryLongCounterName1', 'VeryLongCounterName2')          
and CounterValue > 0
```

This runs automatically every hour (through a C# console app), and I've noticed that with this query I'm getting timeout issues. I just ran it, and it indeed takes about 35 seconds to complete.

So my questions are:

Is there a way to optimize the structure of the staging table so these types of `INSERT`s to other tables don't take that long?

Or is it possible to optimize the `INSERT` query? The reason I have the staging table is because I need to store the data, even if it's for the current month. No matter what's done, the staging table will have tons of rows.

Do you guys have any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Why c#?  This is a work for [**SQL Server Agent**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx)

Comment: So what takes most time: read (select) or write (insert)?

Comment: Have you looked at the OUTPUT clause? It may make things slightly more efficient, but that depends on what you have for business logic.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018353/what-is-the-use-of-output-clause-in-sql-server

Comment: @IvanStarostin, I've deleted lots of data, so the time for the SELECT to complete has gone down a bit to about 15 seconds. The INSERT only adds about 1-2 seconds, at most.

Comment: You are going to need an index on `15MinDataRawStaging`, probably `(date, hour, countername)` and possibly countervalue as well, assuming it is selective.

Comment: @StuartLC, I was thinking of adding an index, but I wasn't sure what to include. What do you mean by _selective_? Thanks.

Comment: [Selectivity](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2011/01/25/query-tuning-fundamentals-density-predicates-selectivity-and-cardinality/). Obviously, you want to add as few indexes as possible, and as few columns per index, otherwise the inserts into the staging table will slow. If this extraction is the only meaningful query reading data, you can consider making it the Clustered index.

Comment: Actually you have to test and probably compromise whether to use indexes and speed up selects but slowdown all data modifications or have fast inserts and deletes but slow select. Staging table is not a regular/persistent one so optimization scenario may be not that clear and straightforward. One of possible scenarios: drop indexes before inserts and deletes, create/rebuild on select, drop again. You have to test it. 15 seconds is not that much. And remember - indexes need space on drive. Regarding your millions of records this may be also a significant factor.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to partition `15MinDataRawStaging` into daily or hourly chunks.  The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730.aspx) explains how to do this (better than a Stack Overflow answer).

Partitioning basically stores the table in multiple different files (at least conceptually).  Certain actions can be very efficient.  For instance, dropping a partition is much, much faster than dropping the individual records.  In addition, fetching data from a single partition should be fast -- and in your case, the most recent partition will be in memory, making everything faster.

Depending on how the data is used, indexes might also be appropriate.  But for this volume of data and the way you are using it, partitions seem like the key idea.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the staging table has only one purpose, viz for the `INSERT` into `DownTime`, you can trade off a small amount of storage and insert performance (into the staging table) to improve the final ETL performance by adding a clustered index matching the query used in extraction:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX MyIndex 
      ON [15MinDataRawStaging]([Date], [Hour], [Minute], RawId);
```

I've added `RawId` in order to allow uniqueness (otherwise a 4 byte uniquefier would have been added in any event).

You'll also want to do some trial and error by testing whether adding `[CounterName]` and / or `[CounterValue]` to the index (but before `RawId`) will improve the overall process throughput (i.e. both Staging insertion and Extraction into the final `DownTime` table)